# Passing variable to view laravel from controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to display a `variable` in my `view` in `laravel4` and every time I try to access it from the `view` I get the following `error`

```
Undefined variable: message (View: C:\wamp\www\app.tld\app\views\admin\book\index.blade.php)
```

This is my `Controller function`

```
$user = Sentry::authenticate($credentials, false);
            if($user){
                if($user->hasAccess('admin')){//Admin Base Controller - Dashboard Display welcome
                    return Redirect::action('BookController@index')->with('message', 'Welcome Administrator');
                }else{//User Base Controller - Dashboard Display 
                    return Redirect::to('user/dashboard/')->with('message', 'Welcome User');
                }
            }
```

I pass `variable` this way:

```
return Redirect::action('BookController@index')->with('message', 'Welcome Administrator');
```

I'm just wondering what I am doing wrong? Is it that I'm passing it to the `BookController` as opposed to the `View`?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using with in this instance will put the data within the Session as flash data. To pass the data to the view you would have to use;

```
View::make('view.path', $data);
```

To access the data in which you are passing it, use;

```
Session::get('message')
```

reference: [this](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#redirects)